# EASy68K Assembly - first program errors

Tags: assembly, easy68k

I'm new to assembly language, so I'm having a little trouble with my first program. I am supposed to basically recreate the following code, except in assembly language obviously. Can anyone help me fix the errors and help me get my program to work properly? I think I am close.

Original non-assembly Code:

```
Q = 7;
P = 15;  // also test on P = 14 and P = 6
if (P > 12)
  P = 8 * P + 4;   // Requirement: use ASL for multiplied by 8
else
  P = P - Q;
print P;
```

Here is what I have so far, but I'm getting errors. I'll post the errors at the bottom.

```
START   ORG     $1000   //Program starts at loc $1000
IF      CMP     #12,P   //Is P > 12?
        BLE     ENDIF   //If P < 12, go to ENDIF
        ASL     #3,P    //Shift left 3 times (Multiply P * 8)
        ADD     #4,P    //P + 4 
ENDIF   SUB     Q,P     //P - Q

* Data section
    ORG $2000    //Data starts at loc 2000
P   DC.W    15  //int P = 15;
Q   DC.W    7   //int Q = 7;
    END START
```

Line 4: ERROR: Invalid addressing mode 
Line 7: ERROR: Invalid addressing mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you keep the [M68000 Programmer's Reference Manual](http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf) around to look up the correct way of using instructions.

`ASL` has no `#<data>,<ea>` form. It *does* have a `<ea>` form, so you can do `ASL P` three times. Or you can move `P` into a register, shift it 3 bits to the left, and put the result back in `P`.

Likewise, there's no `<ea>,<ea>` form of `SUB`. One solution would be to move the `Q` into a `D`-register, and subtract that register from `P`.